# check whether the given date value is valid or not in python with django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-class-based-views

I need to check whether the given input value of date is valid or not in python. I normally used datetime.strptime is to check for date. Am getting Value Error doesn't match format when i given the input value date '06-06-'. It's wrong only but i want to display the output like invalid.

```
  if (datetime.strptime(s,'%m-%d-%y')):
       print "valid"
  else:
       print "Invalid"
```

1 . s = '06-06-15'
       when i given the input value like above, it display the correct output value "Valid"

2. s = '06-06-'
      when i given the input value like above, am getting error like **time data '06-13' does not match format '%m-%d-%y'**. But i want to display the output "Invalid"

Please anyone suggest me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is just how it works.

> ValueError is raised if the date_string and format can’t be parsed by
>   time.strptime()

Just turn it to

```
datetime.strptime(s,'%m-%d-%y'):
       print "valid"
except ValueError:
       print "Invalid"
```